# apache axis 2 CLOSE_WAIT issue

Tags: apache-axis

I have generated web service client using apache axis 2 1.6.2. 
On every request new connection is created and upon successful completion of request/ on error connection is not closed. That cause connection timeout problem to future requests. 
I have checked through netstat command and there are all connection present with CLOSE_WAIT status and does not release the connection.

All connection are not release by apache axis 2 client automatically.
I have found two ways but don't know that will work or not or it can create any ripple effect.
one is to set AUTO_RELEASE_CONNECTION_PROPERTY and second is REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT

I have generated client through myeclipse by using apache axis 2

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue in my previous project & I get it resolved by using Spring's WS managed bean. This issue arises, because you are making port object each time, which create http connection each time and not properly closed.

See the following code,

```
    <bean id="viewBillInfo"
    class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean"
    p:serviceInterface="com.javaplex.CustomerInfoInterface"
    p:wsdlDocumentUrl="http://10.0.5.50:8080/portal/CustomerInfoPort?wsdl"
    p:namespaceUri="http://ws.customergen.com/" p:serviceName="CustomerInfo"
    p:portName="CustomerInfoPort">
```

here is the complete article how to setup spring based beans which give your optimum performance.

http://www.javaplex.com/spring-jax-ws-client-for-best-performance/